# IIS Advanced logging: enable for a website but disable for a virtual dir below it

Tags: iis, logging

I've been googling for hours, but can't seem to find any info on this...

Is there a way I can enable "IIS Advanced Logging" for a website, but disable for a child virtual directory?

I tried "disabling" or even "removing" the "log-difinition" at the subdir level but it doesn't let me to (shows an error message).

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I'm so stupid. Found a solution 10 minutes after posting the question.

You should add a FILTERING rule to the log-definition at the website level, that will filter http-requests targeted to the virtual subdirectory (by looking at the URL field for example).

More info here: http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/advanced-logging-module/advanced-logging-for-iis-log-filtering